# PDFBox - How to convert Xheight to points

Tags: pdf, height, extract, pdfbox, font-size

I am trying to find the Xheight of a font using [Pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org).

`font` is type of `PDFont`

```
println(font.name + ": " + font.fontDescriptor.xHeight)
```

Output of this is for font size 16pt:

```
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT: 546.0
```

But I am not able to identify how to convert this 546.0 into points or pixel or mm.

Comment: See the PrintTextLocations.java or DrawPrintTextLocations.java examples in the sourcee code download. The actual size depends on the current transformation matrix in the PDF and your own matrix when rendering.

Comment: I can see `font.fontMatrix` as `[0.001,0.0,0.0,0.001,0.0,0.0]
` for the font. But I don't know how to use this matrix. Is this the right thing I am looking at?

Comment: I forgot that one, it is yet another thing to consider. This one means you have to divide by 1000. Btw the xHeight isn't always reliable, and is optional: "The font’s x height: the vertical coordinate of the top of flat nonascending lowercase letters (like the letter x), measured from the baseline, in fonts that have Latin characters. Default value: 0.".

Comment: I understood x-height pretty well (as far as I think) but I want to understand what is the unit measure of the value 546/1000?
Since the font size is 16pt and 0.546pt is not close to the xheight I measured as (10.5pts) using adobe illustrator.

Comment: 1 unit = 1/72 inch. But as I wrote, the current current transformation matrix also plays a role because it inflates / reduces whatever is rendered. You have to look at and understand the content stream of that page.

Comment: Yogesh, in other words, please share the PDF in question for which you tried to measure that value. Or provide the **UserUnit** value of the page, the current transformation matrix, and the text matrix at the time the text in question is drawn. (And be aware that such values can often be incorrect without anyone noticing because hardly any program uses them.)

Comment: @mkl https://ufile.io/wp3eyliu (30-day expiry link) this is the file I am using for testing purpose.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr sorry to annoy you again and again but I need help.
below are the some of the values for `textPosition.textMatrix` values.
```
[2.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,325.3544,579.1909]
[2.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,325.7684,579.1909]
[2.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,326.7944,579.1909]
[2.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,327.8204,579.1909]
```
a is Scale_x
b is Shear_x
c is Shear_y
d is Scale_y
e is offset x
f is offset y
How to use those values for Xheight.

Comment: The scale values are 2 so you just multiply with 2. So it would be 546 / 1000 * 2 units.

Comment: the matrix values I posted above were of font size 2.
For font size 16pt, the matrix appears to be `[16.02,0.0,0.0,16.02,185.99182,546.7775]` where it seems 16.02 is the font size which(546*16.02/1000) is not close to the actual x-height(10.5)

Comment: We told you it's unreliablle. But `8.736` is somewhat near to `10.5`. And don't forget that this is not an actual height, it is assumed to be the height of a glyph like 'x'.

Comment: @YogeshChuahan In the file you shared there are two text chunks, one at 22pt font size, one at 28pt font size. You mention a font size of 16pt. Are you sure you shared the correct file?

Comment: The font in the file you shared has a **XHeight** of 484. The current transformation matrix is unchanged, the **UserUnit** is not set, the text matrices are `[22 0 0 22 235.5 653.8896]` and `[28 0 0 28 235.5005 564.3721]`. The font matrices are standard. Thus, the calculated values would be 10.648 and 13.552. The values at the bars left thereof are 10.654 / 10.872 for the first and 14.153 for the latter chunk. Thus, the calculated values are pretty near to those values (albeit not equal).

Comment: Thanks, @mkl and @Tilman 
The file share is one of those for which I am testing. and the other file with many fonts is https://ufile.io/yc0vrf83 here.
In this file let's take fonts like CourierNew where the deviation is large. 

By the way `fontSize*Xheight/1000` this is what has been concluded so far. 
And as you said this is not reliable enough. I am also concluding from your statements that there is no way to find out the exact Xheight.

Comment: You can find the exact height. This is done (except for type 3 fonts) in DrawPrintTextLocations.java with the cyan rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

When you shared the PDF you took your information from, the cause became clear: **The information in the font at hand simply is broken.**

#### Details

As an example you refer to *CourierNew* in your example file *font-list-1.pdf*.

This font is used on page 2, the associated **FontDescriptor** is this object:

```
44 0 obj
<<
  /StemV 42
  /FontName/CourierNewPSMT
  /FontStretch/Normal
  /FontWeight 400
  /Flags 34
  /Descent -300
  /FontBBox[-21 -680 638 1021]
  /Ascent 832
  /FontFamily(Courier New)
  /CapHeight 578
  /XHeight -578
  /Type/FontDescriptor
  /ItalicAngle 0
>>
endobj
```

So the font's **XHeight** value is `-578`. Which means it is rubbish in multiple ways:

- It is negative. According to the specification the **XHeight** value is *the vertical coordinate of the top of flat nonascending lowercase letters (like the letter x), measured from the baseline* (ISO 32000-1, Table 122 – Entries common to all font descriptors). Having a negative value, therefore, means that all those *flat nonascending lowercase letters* are drawn completely way under the baseline.

  This obviously is nonsense for a fairly normal font like CourierNew.

  When loading the font descriptor, PDFBox executes a sanity check and takes the absolute value here which is why you have not seen the negative sign.
- The absolute value of **XHeight** equals the **CapHeight** value which is specified as *the vertical coordinate of the top of flat capital letters, measured from the baseline* (ibidem).

  Ignoring the negative **XHeight** sign (which is nonsense, see above), therefore, the font claims that *flat nonascending lowercase letters* and *flat capital letters* reach up to the same top coordinate.

  This obviously is nonsense for CourierNew.

(The **XHeight** values of many other fonts in your sample file are similarly broken.)

#### How else to get a sensible x height value

If you really need a x height value of your fonts, you should inspect the drawing instructions for the flat nonascending lowercase letters in them and derive a x height value from their respective heights.

(This wont always succeed because those fonts may be available as embedded subsets only, and such subsets might be void of flat nonascending lowercase letters.)